# Cannot resolve scoped service Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.IViewBufferScope from root provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to use in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 web app this sample [RazorViewEngineEmailTemplates](https://github.com/ianrufus/BlogPosts/tree/master/RazorViewEngineEmailTemplates) to create an html email body from View. But when I run it and my controller gets an ajax request, I get this error:

> > Cannot resolve scoped service Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.IViewBufferScope from root provider

It's probably coming from resolving dependencies in the [RazorViewToStringRenderer class](https://github.com/ianrufus/BlogPosts/blob/master/RazorViewEngineEmailTemplates/RazorViewEngineEmailTemplates/Templating/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs) but I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ok, the problem was I used renderer from a Singleton service (EmailerService). I changed its registration to Scoped and it all works now:

```
services.AddScoped<IEmailer, EmailerService>();
```

Answer (score 7):

When a service gets injected as scoped, the dependent class must also be injected as scoped.

Unfortunately, this does not work for every use case. When creating the E-Mail service statically, you don't have an HTTP Context.

In my case, I had a scheduled Task that was executed statically by Hangfire:

```cs
var mailer = ServiceProviderSinleton.Instance.GetService(typeof(IEmailer))
```

When you need that scoped service from a static context, you have two options:

1. use a dependency injection framework that gives you more control over the injection context. I highly recommend `DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` from NuGet. ([Documentation](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/ReuseAndScopes))
2. disable the scope validation:

```cs
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureLogging(builder => builder.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, dispose: true))
    .UseKestrel(options => options.ConfigureEndpoints(configuration))
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<TStartup>()
    .UseSerilog()
    .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false)
    .Build();
```

Comment: With ASP.NET Core 2.1 you can now create a scope manually: ```using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; 
using(var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope()) {
var myScopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyScopedService>();
}
```

Comment: @MovGP0 Where does that code even go and I how do I force it to work? Do I need everything that you've set? Is it a replacement for something else?

Comment: @RobertBurke, I think he's referring to a setup like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381457/522859. I implemented that after hitting the same problem and it resolved it for me.