# Create scope factory in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to create scoped container in asp.net core and use it in 2 methods of my singleton method.

I've tried create this in each method of sigleton. it works, but i think it is overhead.

```
var scopeFactory = _serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
var scopedContainer = scope.ServiceProvider;
```

I write it in each method when i need it. I think it is logic mistake. Please, explain me how to do it correct? thank you

Comment: Technically speaking. The mistake is likely that your service is a singleton in the first place. If  it needs to use scoped services, there's a strong argument that it should be scoped as well.

Comment: The mistake is likely that you have many methods that require this logic. Only infrastructural components, part of your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) should require this, which would lead to a handful (at most) of places where you would need to create a new scope.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It is technically not incorrect the way you do it. If you are within a singleton service and you need to access scoped services, then you *should* create a new service scope and retrieve the services from that scope’s service provider. And when you are done, you should also **dispose the scope**.

In practice, you can simplify this a bit. You should avoid having to inject `IServiceProvider` directly into a service. Instead, you can just inject the `IServiceScopeFactory` directly. And then you should also create the scope with a `using` statement to make sure that it is disposed properly after use.

So an example singleton service could look like this:

```
public class ExampleSingletonService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public ExampleSingletonService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();

            db.Add(new Foo());
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there isn’t really *that* much overhead for this. But of course this makes you think twice about whether you want to use a scoped service within a singleton or not.

Comment: Thanks for this, have been looking through quite a few answers but this one explained it very clearly!