# MassTransit unable to use IRequestClient - dependency injection issue

Tags: .net, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

In the Startup.ConfigureServices I'm adding MassTransit configuration

```
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
       config.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
       config.AddRequestClient<RegisterCarOwner>();
       config.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq();
});
  
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

in the handler I'm using this client in order to send message

```
public class RegisterCarOwnerHandler : IRequestHandler<RegisterCarOwnerCommand, Unit>
{
    private readonly IRequestClient<RegisterCarOwner> _registerOwnerClient;
    public RegisterCarOwnerHandler(IRequestClient<RegisterCarOwner> registerOwnerClient)
    {
       _registerOwnerClient = registerOwnerClient
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(RegisterCarOwnerCommand command, CancellationToken token)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[xxxx.RegisterCarOwnerCommand] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: xxxx.TestHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'MassTransit.IRequestClient`1[RegisterCarOwner.RegisterCarOwnerHandler]' while attempting to activate 'xxxx.RegisterCarOwnerHandler '.)'

Update:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) { Configuration = configuration; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ....        
        var rabbitMqConf = new RabbitMqConfiguration();
        this.Configuration.GetSection(RabbitMqConfiguration.SectionName).Bind(rabbitMqConf);

        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddRequestClient<RegisterCarOwner>();
            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitMqConf.ConnectionUrl), c => 
                {
                    c.Username(rabbitMqConf.Username);
                    c.Password(rabbitMqConf.Password);
                });
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ....
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IRequestClient<T>` is scoped, and you're trying to resolve it without a scope.

Also, your bus configuration is seriously outdated, change:

`config.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq();`

to the supported syntax:

`config.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) => {});`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Any idea how to resolve IRequestClient in the handler?

Comment: Maybe look up other answers related to scopes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381457/1882

Comment: I'd like to see this called out better in the docs here: https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/requests#request-client

Comment: Maybe adding reference to https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/requests#request-client further down into the document, into the section on using the request client? Or is that completely different?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when I want inject the IRequestClient<>,
Based on Docs there is no need for configuration but you could do that with

> A request client can be resolved using dependency injection for any valid message type, no configuration is required. By default, request messages are published and should be consumed by only one consumer/receive endpoint connected to the message broker.

```
x.AddRequestClient<CheckOrderStatus>
```

but it does work only when config this manually, or even if you use both Rabbit, InMemory you should use this after configurations.

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddMessageScheduler(schedulerEndpoint);

    x.AddConsumers(assemblies);

    // Doesn`t work here :|
    x.AddRequestClient<AddComponentToMenuStructure>();

    if (Setting.General.MessageBroker == MessageBroker.RabbitMQ)
    {
        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host(bpmsSetting.RabbitMq.Host, bpmsSetting.RabbitMq.VirtualPath, h =>
            {
                h.Username(bpmsSetting.RabbitMq.Username);
                h.Password(bpmsSetting.RabbitMq.Password);
                h.Heartbeat(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            });

            // More Config

            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new NameFormatter(bpmsSetting));
        });

    }
    else if (Setting.General.MessageBroker == MessageBroker.InMemory)
    {
         x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
            {
                // More Config
            
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new 
NameFormatter(bpmsSetting));
            });
    }

    // Here
    x.AddRequestClient<AddComponentToMenuStructure>();
});
```