# C# Timer - Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, service

In the code I posted, it works in the first period. When entering the second period, it gives this error:

> Unhandled exception.
> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.

I have checked everything. What do you think could be the reason?

```
public class EmailVerificationService
{
private Timer? _timer;
private string? _email;
private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

public EmailVerificationService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

}

public void Start(string email)
{
    _email = email;
    _timer = new Timer(CheckVerificationExpiration, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
}

private async void CheckVerificationExpiration(object state)
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    using IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    using AppDbContext dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
    User? user = await dbContext.Users
        .Where(u => u.Email == _email && now >= u.ConfirmCodeExpires)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (user != null)
    {
        dbContext.Users.Remove(user);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
}
```

I checked everything. I changed service life time. I then tried creating the `IServiceFactory` in the `Start` method. It just didn't work to use the same service for all of them.

Comment: private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

Comment: @Ihdina doesn't work. Same problem (( Because the problem is not in that part. The problem is in this code: `IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();` When applying for the second time, it says that it has already been disposed object.

Comment: What problem is this supposed to solve? My suspicion is that you don't actually need a timer. Btw: there are several different timers in dotnet, so it is always advisable to be specific about which one you are using.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200200/net-core-iservicescopefactory-createscope-vs-iserviceprovider-createscope-e

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper Thank you so much. I did it with IServiceFactory and it worked. When I tested it, didn't work because of a problem with AppDbContext service life time.

Comment: Remove `using` in front of `IServiceScope` and `AppDbContext`

Comment: What is the lifetime for ``EmailVerificationService``? how do you call the start method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `IServiceScopeFactory` instead of `IServiceProvider` in the constructor.

The lifetime of `IServiceScopeFactory` is `Singleton`. It means you can have access to this interface everywhere.

The lifetime of `IServiceProvider` is `Scoped`. So it seems when your `EmailVerificationService` will be out of scope then `IServiceProvider` will be disposed and you will see the error.

Additional information can be found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72368377/7126845) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381457/7126845).